# Behaviour of Array bang methods

Tags: ruby, arrays

Some bang version of `Array` methods are like `compact!`, `reject!`, `flatten!`, `uniq!` return `nil` if no changes were made:

```
[1,[2]].flatten!
# => [1, 2]
[1,2].flatten!
# => nil
[1,[2]].flatten
# => [1, 2]
[1,2].flatten
# => [1, 2]

[1,2,nil].compact!
# => [1, 2]
[1,2].compact!
# => nil
[1,2,nil].compact
# => [1, 2]
[1,2].compact
# => [1, 2]
```

If they did it this way, there has to be a reason. Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The bang (`!`) methods do modify the current object in place, but they do return `nil` if there are no affected elements per [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002219).  This is useful if, for whatever reason, you need to do something if you did modify the array in question.

```
if array.flatten!
  puts "Oh yeah... flattened that array!"
end
```

Comment: That is a good point. But you can't do say `return array.flatten!`, which, to me, would seem useful either

Comment: True.  If that is what you want, you'd say `return array.flatten` (no bang) which would return you a flattened copy of the original array.

Comment: Which forces me to make a copy where I don't need to. Which is exactly how I got into trouble using banged version in the first place.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, you'd need to `return array.flatten! || array` (or split it into two statements) which isn't supremely elegant, IMO, but that is the only alternative I can think of at the moment.

Comment: It probably was a design flaw that has not been fixed as it would break code. I guess everbody would agree that returning the object itself is more important that knowing if it changed. The Array class is not even coherent: Array#sort! always return the object, even if no changes were made. Python on other hand has a different policy: in-place operations return nil (None) to emphasize it. Lastly: when you're returning an object after an inplace operation maybe the safest and clearest is a simple: 1) obj.operation! + 2) (return) obj.

Answer (score 4):

> I was always under impression that
>   bang version of `Array` methods are
>   only different in the way that they
>   modify object in place.

Perhaps the problem here is that this impression is not really a correct one: [according to David A. Black](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist), **`!` does not mean that the method changes its receiver; `!` means that this method is the "dangerous" version of an otherwise equivalent method**, which has the same name minus the `!`.

Now danger takes many forms (*emphasis mine*):

> Sometimes you get more than one kind
>   of "danger" even within one bang
>   method. Take `String#gsub!`. This
>   method changes its receiver:
>
> ```
> str = "David" 
> str.gsub!(/$/, " Black")
> str                        # David Black
> ```
>
> It also differs from `gsub` (non-bang)
>   in that if the string does not change,
>   `gsub` returns a copy of the unchanged
>   string but `gsub!` returns nil:
>
> ```
> str.gsub(/xyz/, "blah")    # David Black
> str.gsub!(/xyz/, "blah")   # nil
> str                        # David Black
> ```
>
> **The ! in `gsub!` gives you a heads-up:
>   it warns you of danger, and that means
>   that before you use the method, you
>   should find out exactly how it
>   behaves.** (A simple "`ri String#gsub!`"
>   should do it.)

This "heads-up" semantics also applies to the bang methods of `Array`.

Comment: I also read this post - it makes no sense. The meaning of 'dangerous' is at best determined as a mark of counter-intuitive behaviour. Well, perhaps, they shouldn't have made it that way in the first place?

Comment: And `before you use the method, you should find out exactly how it behaves` is clearly not the ruby way, where normally the entire ecosystem of conventions naturally leads to the right thing.