# Use .reverse_merge or .merge in default methods params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

You can do both

```
def setup(options = {})
  options.reverse_merge :size => 25, :velocity => 10
end
```

and

```
def setup(options = {})
  { :size => 25, :velocity => 10 }.merge(options)
end
```

to assign default values in method's params.

The question is: which one is better? Which one you would rather use? Is there any difference in performance, code readability or what ever else?

**EDIT: I added bang (`!`) by accident... didn't mean to ask about difference  between no bang method vs bang method**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tend to use the `reverse_merge` approach:

```
options.reverse_merge(size: 25, velocity: 10)
```

Reason being:

1. You don't have to write the curly brackets for the hash when the hash is used as a method argument.
2. Reading left-to-right you know right away that this line of the code is dealing with the passed-in options hash, vs first learning about a new hash then realizing options are being merged into it.
3. If you *do* want to update the original `options` hash it *is* just as easy as adding `!` to the `reverse_merge!` method. Whereas with the other approach you now have to add a variable (re)assignment.

Ultimately, I think it's just a stylistic choice and is just up to you and what feels right to your brain.

Comment: Caveat: Your code now requires ActiveSupport (or a monkey-patched Hash class).

Answer (score 3):

Merges the caller into other_hash. For example,

```
options = options.reverse_merge(size: 25, velocity: 10)
```

is equivalent to

```
options = { size: 25, velocity: 10 }.merge(options)
```

This is particularly useful for initializing an options hash with default values.

---

When,  **reverse_merge!(other_hash) public**

Performs the opposite of `merge`, with the `keys` and `values` from the first hash taking precedence over the second. Modifies the receiver in place.

**Note:** The default `:size` and `:velocity` is only set if the options passed in doesn‘t already have those keys set.

via [Ruby](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/reverse_merge) [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/ReverseMerge/reverse_merge!).

Answer (score 1):

Two methods are similar, read this [reverse_merge vs merge](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5186906190/merge-or-reverse-merge-a-hash), but using [Bang versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741892/confusing-behaviour-of-array-bang-methods) to modify the current object in place.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `merge` or `reverse_merge`. However, I would *not* use `merge!` or `reverse_merge!` because they modify the input argument. Take this as an example:

```
def setup(options = {})
  options.reverse_merge! :size => 25, :velocity => 10
end

opts = {size: 10}
setup opts
opts      # => {size: 10, velocity: 25}
```

Our opts object is modified by the setup method! This is an unexpected and probably bad side-effect.

*Note that the above part of this answer refers to an older version of the question. Nevertheless, it's important to note that using the bang version of these methods probably is a bad idea!*

---

My personal preference for Rails would be to use a normal `reverse_merge`:

```
def setup(options = {})
  options = options.reverse_merge(:size => 25, :velocity => 10)
end
```

Note that if you look up the [definition of reverse_merge](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge.rb), it's the exact same as using a regular merge:

```
def reverse_merge(other_hash)
  other_hash.merge(self)
end
```

so feel free to use whichever you like better. The caveat to using `reverse_merge` is that it's a method provided by ActiveSupport and not a method built into Ruby. So if you ever plan on running your code outside of a context where ActiveSupport is available, probably best to just use `merge`.