# What determines if a bang method on a mutable class returns `nil`?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Usually, bang methods on mutable a class such as `String`, `Array`, or `Hash` return `nil` when no modification is made. But some `Array` bang methods, i.e., `collect!`, `map!`, `reverse!`, `rotate!`, `shuffle!`, `sort!`, `sort_by!` and a `Hash` bang method, i.e., `merge!`, never return `nil`. What is the rationale behind this? What makes these methods different from others? I don't see why knowing whether an array was sorted by `sort!` is not useful while knowing whether an array was made unique by `uniq!` is useful.

Comment: For the bang methods listed, except potentially the sorts and merge, will *always* make a modification, so it seems like your question would be better directed only at methods that may *not* make a modification. It also depends on what you mean by "modification", because the writing will always happen, even if it writes the same value.

Comment: @DaveNewton All of them potentially do not change the receiver. For `collect!` and `map!`, if the block is `{|e| e % 3}`, and the elements are numbers, it may not change. `reverse!` does not change when the length is `1` or is symmetric. `rotate!` does not change when the argument is a multiple of the length or is symmetric. `shuffle!` may not change. With modification, I mean a change in at least one element.

Comment: That's why I said it depends on what you mean by "modification". Personally I suspect my reason is why. Anything other than first-source info will be opinion.

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate of the [question you just edited](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3741892/479863)? Seems like pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @engineersmnky From *`!` is[sic] ruby ...* to *... the method did nothing*, I already know. From *essentially useless in this implementation ...* to the end of you comment, I cannot comprehend. But I have the impression that you are looking at the complement of what I am asking. I am asking why these methods are not useful if they returned `nil`. You are answering why other methods are useful if they returned `nil`, which I already know.

Comment: edit I apologize I have deleted my comments. The purpose of these methods is not to alter the receiver itself per say as much as the elements inside the receiver. This is why they do not return `nil`. These methods replace values inside the container so `array.collect!{|e| e}` is in essence replacing the items inside the array with the same item.

Comment: to expand on my previous comment it seems the methods you are asking about the `!` actually indicates the potential mutation of the objects inside rather than the mutation of the containing object. Which now thinking about it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

> [B]ang methods on mutable class[es] return nil when no modification is made...[b]ut some Array bang methods...never return nil.

If there is an "official" rationale (along the lines of an official specification), I'm currently unaware of it. I personally suspect it's simply because some objects use nil as a return value to indicate errors (e.g. index out of range) rather than raising an exception, while others always return a valid object. I very much doubt there's an overriding philosophy there, although there appears to be a general consensus about when to use bang methods when you dig deep enough.

### Bang Methods Aren't Inherently About Mutation

As one example, consider [issue #5009](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5009), which requests:

> [P]lease use bang methods (those that end with !) consistently in the API.

One [useful response](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5009#note-1) says:

> [That bang is destructive] is a common misconception about the use of bang methods in Ruby. Bang does not indicate that a method mutates its receiver, merely that it should be used with caution.

### Some Community Consensus on Bang Methods

There is definitely some consensus among Rubyists about when to use bang methods. The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) currently offers the following guidelines:

> - The names of potentially dangerous methods...should end with an exclamation mark if there exists a safe version of that dangerous method.
> - Define the non-bang (safe) method in terms of the bang (dangerous) one if possible.

These guidelines seem consistent with the general idea that bang methods are about the caller being careful in choosing the method or handling the return value, rather than the bang acting as an indicator of what will be returned.